# Adding new row in vaSpread at run time in VB6

Tags: vb6

I want to insert one duplicate row in vaSpread at runtime.
When user click on Add button.
I found one link about deleting existing [row](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/75921.aspx).
May be this link is useful for you to understand my requirement.
I just want to add new row below current row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't know if that would help, but I had a similar problem where I needed to insert an empty row, but it is even a bit easier to insert a dublicate. I am a bit unsure whether or not it works properly because I get bad results because of other reasons but here is the function I wrote for inserting a row (adjusted to have the inserted row be dublicate rather than empty)

```
Public Sub InsertRow(ByVal index&, ByRef table As vaSpread)
    With table
        table.MaxRows = table.MaxRows + 1
        Dim i
        For i = table.MaxRows To index Step -1
            Dim j
            For j = 1 To table.MaxCols
                Dim tmp
                Call .GetText(j, i, tmp)
                Call .SetText(j, i + 1, tmp)
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Where index is position of the row that is to be dublicated.
What this does is basically copies the content of a row to the next row starting from the end until it reaches the index. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 4 your answer CrrokedBadge, u helpme!

```
sLista.MaxRows = conteo
            sql = "SELECT Descripcion FROM xxx WHERE bActivo=1 ORDER BY Id"
            If (GcDb.dbExecQuery(sql, rs)) Then
                Do Until rs.EOF
                    tmp = rs("Descripcion")
                    Call sLista.SetText(1, k, tmp)
                    k = k + 1
                    rs.MoveNext
                Loop
                rs.Close
            End If
```

Comment: How does that address the original question?